# Разновидность дорожного блокиратора

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какое название имеет этот ограничитель?

Answer (score 2):

**Дорожный конус сигнальный** (различной высоты: 320 мм, 520 мм, 750 мм) используется как ограждение при проведении дорожно-строительных работ или для обозначения парковочных мест, перераспределения транспортных потоков, для обозначения аварийных участков и мест ДТП и т. п.
Изготавливается из экологически безопасного пластичного ПВХ.

При эксплуатации (-40°C — +40°C) конус сохраняет пластичность и восстанавливает свою форму после наезда автомобиля. Полосы на конусах выполняются специальной световозвращающей пленкой, что удобно для эксплуатации в ночное время суток.
Конструктивные особенности конусов позволяют легко их хранить  и перемещать.
Дорожный конус сигнальный высотой 520 или 750мм может комплектоваться дополнительным утяжелителем (для повышения устойчивости).
Возможна установка импульсных светодиодных сигнальных фонарей.

[Конусы дорожные сигнальные](https://www.idn500.ru/fencing/cones/)